# how to integrate optparse options with the variables names in python

Tags: python, optparse

I am very newbie to python and to `optparse` module in general. I have figured out how to add options in  python script using `optparse` but having trouble linking the options with my variable names in python.

```
import sys
from optparse import OptionParser

def main ():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="in_filename",
                      help="Input fasta file", metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_option("-o", "--out", dest="out_filename",
                      help="Output fasta file", metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_option("-i", "--id", dest="id",
                      help="Id name to change", metavar="ID")
    (options,args) = parser.parse_args()

    with open(f, 'r') as fh_in:
        with open(o, 'w') as fh_out:
            id = i
            result = {}
            count = 1
            for line in fh_in:
                line = line.strip()
                if line.startswith(">"):
                    line = line[1:]
                    result[line] = id + str(count)
                    count = count + 1
                    header = ">" + str(result[line])
                    fh_out.write(header)
                    fh_out.write("\n")
                else:
                    fh_out.write(line)
                    fh_out.write("\n")

main()
```

When i run this i get this below traceback and error:

```
python header_change.py -f consensus_seq.txt -o consensus_seq_out.fa -i "my_test"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/upendrakumardevisetty/Documents/git_repos/scripts/header_change.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/upendrakumardevisetty/Documents/git_repos/scripts/header_change.py", line 18, in main
    with open(f, 'r') as fh_in:
NameError: global name 'f' is not defined
```

Can someone point to me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: First, please print the whole traceback, not just the error string. In this case we can probably guess where it happened, but it's better to not make people guess.

Comment: As a side note, is there a reason you're using `optparse`? As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) explain, it's deprecated in 2.7/3.2. Unless you need your program to run in 2.6 or 3.1, it's better to use `argparse`—especially if you're just learning; no reason to learn something that's already out of date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got two problems here.

---

First, as [the `optparse` tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#tutorial) shows, `optparse` doesn't create global variables, it creates attributes in the `options` namespace that it returns:

> `parse_args()` returns two values:
>
> - `options`, an object containing values for all of your options—e.g. if `--file` takes a single string argument, then `options.file` will be the filename supplied by the user, or `None` if the user did not supply that option
> - `args`, the list of positional arguments leftover after parsing options

So, if the user typed `-f`, you're not going to have `f`, you're going to have `options.f`.

---

Second, `f` isn't the right name anyway. You explicitly specified a different destination, instead of the default:

```
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="in_filename",
                  help="Input fasta file", metavar="FILE")
```

So it's going to do what you asked and store the file in `in_filename`.

---

And likewise for the other options. So, your code should start off like this:

```
with open(options.in_filename, 'r') as fh_in:
    with open(options.out_filename, 'w') as fh_out:
```